# What is V in this circuit?

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws

[image]

This question on kirchoff's second rule every time I calculate it I get +12V but in my book's answers it's -12V.
Could someone solve it and tell me what I'm doing wrong or is the book itself wrong ? I solve it this way: +V+2 -20 +6 =0  -->thus V =-2+20-6=+12V  ... Thanks!

Comment: Books are written by people too.

Comment: The proper answer is V = 12 V. They put in that mistake to test if you are paying attention. So congratulations, you passed the test!

Comment: It's certainly a confusing question, they should have used something other than V for the unknown value. As it stands, it says that V+2V-20V+6V=0, i.e. -11V=0, therefore V=0.

Comment: Start a tour of the loop at the top node. To get to the bottom node, travelling through each resistor in turn, you go: down through 6v; up through 20v; down through 2v. The net result is up through 12v so the bottom node is 12v above the top node.